# Animação não aparece na section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Eae galera estou fazendo um site em bootstrap 4 e quero colocar uma animação com animate.css, como ele é dividio em classes eu so coloco a classe e pronto porém o efeito acontece logo quando carrega a página e gostaria que o efeito aparecesse quando o usuario abaixar o scroll e carregar a section especifica pro efeito. o nome da classe do efeito é 'bounceInLeft' e antes coloca animated então ' animated bounceInLeft' .N CONSIGO FAZER FICA NA SECTION ONDE TEM CONTAINER,ROW COUNTERS NO CASO COM OS ICONS PEQUENOS OS 4 TEXTOS COM H1 QUERIA O EFEITO NESSE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Titulo.</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all-animation.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="caminhodoarquivo/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" 
 integrity="sha384- 
 hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>

<body>
 <div class="mynavbar">
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a href="indexpadrao.html" class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="images/logo.png">
</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria- 
 controls="conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
 label="Alterna navegação">
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="conteudoNavbarSuportado">
   <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       <li class="nav-item">
           <a href="plans.html" class="nav-link text-white">Home</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
           <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">Sobre</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item pr-2">
           <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">Portifolio</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline- 
    light">Contato</button>
       </li>     
   </ul>                  
</div>      
</nav>
    <div class="principal2">
    <h1 class="display-1">Meu Nome é Matheus Luiz.</h1>
   <hr>
    <h3 class="display-1">Sejam Bem-Vindos e conheçam um pouco do  meu 
    trabalho.</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg display-1" 
   style="padding-left:30px;padding-right: 30px;font-size:1.8rem">Saiba 
    mais</button>
     </div> 
</div>
 <section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h3 class="display-4  text-primary">O que eu faço?</h3>
      <p class="h6 pb-5">Veja um pouco mais do que eu faço para tornar os 
   sites ainda mais completos para os padrões do mercado.</p>
     </div>
   <div class="row counters" style="line-height: 28px;">

    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-center animated 
  bounceInLeft">
       <div class="single_service">        
          <div class="ico mb-4"><i class="fab fa-searchengin"></i></div>
            <h2>Search Engine Optimization</h2>
              <p style="color:#4c4c4c;">Cansado de não ter visitas? Seu site 
  no top dos buscadores mais utilizados no mercado como Google e Bing.</p>
       </div>
    </div>

      <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-center animated 
  bounceInLeft">
       <div class="single_service">        
          <div class="ico mb-4"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></div>
            <h2>Design Responsivo</h2>
              <p style="color:#4c4c4c;">Sites que se adaptam as diferentes 
  resoluções de tela e trazem uma ótima experiencia com o usúario e site. 
  </p>
       </div>
            </div>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-center">
       <section class="animated bounceInRight">
        <div class="single_service">        
          <div class="ico mb-4"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></div>
            <h2>Feito com amor e carinho</h2>
              <p style="color:#4c4c4c;">Meus sites são feitos pela paixão de 
   programar e ver resultados incríveis na tela que podem mudar o rumo de 
  empresas.</p>
       </div>
           </section>
       </div>

      <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-center animated 
    bounceInRight">
        <div class="single_service">        
          <div class="ico mb-4"><i class="fas fa-users"></i></div>
            <h2>Sempre a seu favor</h2>
              <p style="color:#4c4c4c;">Tenho técnicas avançadas com meus 
    clientes para atingir exatamente o que os mesmos querem.</p>
       </div>
            </div>

        </div>

  </div>
   </section>
  <section class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4 text-center mt-5 mb-4">Minha habilidades</h1>
   <div class="progress mb-4">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" 
 role="progressbar" style="width: 95%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" 
 aria-valuemax="100"><h3 class="text-center">HTML5</h3></div>
 </div>
 <div class="progress mb-4">
 <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg- 
 dark" 
 role="progressbar" style="width: 94%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" 
 aria-valuemax="100"><h3 class="text-center">CSS3</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress mb-4">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg- 
   success" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="50" aria- 
 valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><h3 class="text-center">RESPONSIVO</h3> 
</div>
  </div>
<div class="progress mb-4">
 <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg- 
 warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 95%" aria-valuenow="75" aria- 
 valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><h3 class="text-center">BOOTSTRAP 4</h3> 
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="progress mb-4">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg- 
   danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 90%" aria-valuenow="100" aria- 
 valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><h3 class="text-center">JAVASCRIPT</h3> 
 </div>
 </div>
</section>

<section class="container">





</section>
 <!-- Primeiro o jsquery -->
 <!-- Segundo o Popper min -->
 <!-- Terceiro o Bootstrap js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/our.js"></script>
<script>
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  $('nav').toggleClass('scrolled',$(this).scrollTop() > 500);
  });

tentei fazer isso aqui , COM NAV FOI PERFEITAMENTE O EFEITO QUE EU QUERIA 
 MAS N CONSIGO FAZER FICA NA SECTION ONDE TEM CONTAINER,ROW COUNTERS NO CASO   


     $(window).scroll(function(){
  $('row counters').toggleClass('animated bounceInLeft',$(this).scrollTop() 
   > 700);
  });
</script>
 </body>  
 </html>
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi vc quer que a animação só acorra quando o Scroll atingir determinado elemento correto? Pois se vc colocar a classe de cara a animação vai acontecer antes que o usuário faça o Scroll até o elemento que está mais para baixo na página é isso?

Comment: Cara vc consegue resolver isto facilmente sem utilização de uma linha de **Javascript**. Tem uma biblioteca chamada **WOW.js**, ela é usada juntamente com animate, a animate é só `CSS` a wow é `JS`, com a wow vc determina a duração da animação e quando a animação deve acontecer, tudo na tag html que quer o efeito. O link para a biblioteca é este https://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/